# joinInner zend not display a query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to display all users where "rola" = 3 from table user. Table user must be related with table kursyuser. My query:
 `$this->view->allUser = $user->fetchAll($user->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)->from('kursyuser')->joinInner('kursyuser', 'user.id=kursyuser.id_user', array('id', 'id_user'))->where('user.rola=3'));`

Page display 3 errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.rola' in 'where clause'' in C:\wamp64\www\driver\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 235

( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.rola' in 'where clause' in C:\wamp64\www\driver\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228

( ! ) Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.rola' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `kursyuser`.*, `kursyuser_2`.`id`, `kursyuser_2`.`id_user` FROM `kursyuser` INNER JOIN `kursyuser` AS `kursyuser_2` ON user.id=kursyuser.id_user WHERE (user.rola=3) in C:\wamp64\www\driver\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 235
```

I have similar query and this query works:
`//$this->view->kursy = $kursy->fetchAll($kursy->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)->from('kursy')->joinInner('kursyuser', 'kursy.id=kursyuser.id_kursy', array('id_user', 'id_kursy'))->where('kursyuser.id_user=?',$id));`

Comment: please provide the definition of `$user` it seem that your model bonded with `kursyuser` table but not `user`?

Comment: this is my code: ` Zend_Loader::loadClass('user');
  $user = new user();` 
and this work : `$this->view->allUser = $user->fetchAll($user->select()->where('rola=3'));`

but joinInner doesn't work

Comment: `::loadClass('user');` please show `user` class definition